# Catching all exceptions and logging information

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I am a Java programmer working with C++ code, and need some help with exception handling.

I have code in the following structure:

```
try{
...
}
catch( ... ) 
{
    log("Exception occurred");
}
```

An exception is occurring, but the try block is really massive and debugging is not an option, so I need to minimally modify the code to give me relevant info on the exception.

So I added the following catch block before the existing catch block (working with my Java knowledge and referring to C++ guides):

```
catch(exception e)
{
    log(e.what());
}
```

However, I am still getting the old message - "Exception occurred". The code in try block contains a lot of low level functions like `strncpy, memcpy` etc.

Why is this `catch` block not working as expected? What can I do to  get information on the exception that is occurring and on which line, similar to the stack trace that Java so easily gives.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "exception" in `C` (at least not in the sense of a control-flow mechanism).

Comment: @Mankarse, `std::exception` does exist in C++ standard library. To Shailesh, you can use gdb to debug such non-standard exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the backtrace from the catch block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283943/getting-the-backtrace-from-the-catch-block)

Comment: @iammilind: This question was previously tagged C, and talked about handling exception handling in "C/C++" code. It has since been edited, as Shailesh Tainwala is clearly writing C++, not C.

Comment: worth to mention that you should put your catch block before the catch(...), also you should catch by reference and not by value

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: In the question the guy specified that he put his catch block _before_ `catch( ... )`.

Comment: sorry, you are correct, I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to debug and determine if the exception is an C++ exception.
Note that divide by `0` etc are runtime exceptions not supported by C++, so it can be anything literally.

A catch-all handler will only catch valid C++ exceptions not all exceptions(which can be plenty).

Comment: How can I get information about the exception that occurred from the catch-all handler?

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala: You cannot, and hence catch-all is to be avoided to begin with.It just hides your problems, not solves it.Your best bet is to determine what goes wrong by debugging, there is no easy way.

Comment: @Als: I got from the question that the catch-all did catch the exception.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I didn't get the same actually, perhaps the OP should clarify.

Answer (score 6):

First, you should catch by reference (generally const), so your new `catch` block should read:

```
try {

} catch(std::exception const& e) {
    log(e.what());
} catch(...) {
    log("Exception occurred");
}
```

Second, in C++ you may throw any value. Even of type `int`. If your codebase include such unsavvy `throw` statements, I pity you.

Since you come from Java, I would check if you mistakenly used a `throw new XXXX` which would throw a pointer (to a dynamically allocated value) instead of a value. The `new` is unnecessary in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because those exceptions are not derived from `exception` class. In C++ any type can be an exception, for example `string`, `int`, etc. Anyway if you want to catch `exception` you should probably catch a reference to the `exception &`.

Comment: If the existing catch-all handler didn't catch the exception, the exception thrown is not an c++ exception at all.