# How to get what() and back trace at the same time for an uncaught exception?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

When an uncaught exception happens in my application, I can get the `what()` string of the exception by adding a global `catch` to my `main()` function, something like:

```
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << "\n";
}
```

I can also get the stack trace of the location where the exception was thrown by calling `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbol()` from inside a `std::terminate()` handler (set by calling `std::set_terminate()`). For example (ignore the memory leak):

```
void terminate_handler()
{
    void** buffer = new void*[15];
    int count = backtrace(buffer, 15);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(buffer, count, STDERR_FILENO);
}

…

std::set_terminate(terminate_handler);
```

But when I try to combine the two approaches by rethrowing the exception using `throw;` in my global `catch`, I'm getting stack trace to that `catch`, not to the location where the exception was originally thrown.

Is there some way I can do both (get the stack trace for the location where the exception was originally thrown and also get the value of its `what()`) at the same time?

Comment: When you catch an exception, the stack has already been unwound, so there is not longer any trace of earlier functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Right, I get that. My question is, is there some way to work around that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ stacktrace from the function an exception is thrown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271132/c-stacktrace-from-the-function-an-exception-is-thrown)... Or you can implement your own exception type that gets the trace in the constructor

Comment: @svick Unfortunately, you'd need the exception to be populated with the stack details at the point where it is thrown.  It is not possible to reconstitute that information at the point where you catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
void terminate_handler()
{
    void** buffer = new void*[15];
    int count = backtrace(buffer, 15);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(buffer, count, STDERR_FILENO);

    //etc.
    auto ptr = std::current_exception();
    try { std::rethrow_exception(ptr); }
    catch (std::exception & p) { std::cout << p.what() << std::endl;}
}
```

Comment: Honestly I am not even sure that this is not UB (2 exceptions active at the same time? Is `std::current_exception()` supposed to be invoked outside a `catch` clause?). I just tested this with G++ and it works.

Comment: `backtrace()` is already a GCC extension, so I'm not sure how does what the standard say matters. And I think that 2 active exceptions are okay. Or do you think that you can't do anything that could throw an exception in a `catch` clause?

Comment: It's not like a `catch` clause, it's more like throwing-and-cathing in a destructor. Imagine `ptr` contains an exception which is not derived from `std::exception`: it won't catch it and you'll end up with 2 active exceptions (the one captured with `current_exception` and the one thrown by `rethrow_exception`).