# Exception handling in MFC

Tags: c++

This is a basic question after coding `try` which covers a range of c/c++ statements.

If the catch block is entered, how do I know which statement was the culprit?

Comment: You don't. If you need that kind of granularity, then either maintain a state variable to identify each step, or split the big `try` into individual `try` blocks around each statement.

Comment: If you need to know, chances are that your code isn't exception safe (with either the *basic* or *strong* guarantee). Too little information to give a helpful answer. Please provide a specific code sample and explain, why it matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code

```
try {
    if (a)
        throw 0;
    else if (b)
        throw 0;
    else if (c)
        throw 0;
    throw 1;
} catch (int i) {
    // << here
}
```

If `i` is `0`, there is no language-specified mechanism to tell which `throw 0` threw. We can only distinguish between `0` and `1` throws. There are compiler specific hacks ([How can I print stack trace for caught exceptions in C++ & code injection in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665829/how-can-i-print-stack-trace-for-caught-exceptions-in-c-code-injection-in-c)) but nothing standard.