# Running function on C++ throw in gcc/linux?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++17, libstdc++

Is there any way in gcc/linux to have a user-defined function called immediately after any C++ throw statement executes, but before the stack is unwound to the catch?  (I want to capture a stacktrace.)

(In gdb I can write `catch throw`.  Anyway to do that programmatically short of a compiler extension?)

Comment: I answered a similar question a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11674810/168175, with stack trace and rethrow.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `libstdc++`, you could override `__cxa_throw()`.

For instance:

```
#include <cstring>

void __cxa_throw(void *, void *, void (*)(void *)) {
    std::puts("bad luck");
}

int main() {
    throw 13;
}
```

Comment: @MarshallClow Well, when you are there you can do whatever you want, including calling the proper thrower.

Comment: If it's somebody else's program, you can use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - I have an example [here](https://github.com/AaronDMarasco/rpm-cookbook#spoofing-rpm-host-name).

Comment: A better example [here](https://github.com/AaronDMarasco/file-stealer).

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Indeed! Thanks for those links.

Comment: How would you call the "proper thrower" from within __cxa_throw?  As Marshall said, once the function is complete I want the exception to be thrown and caught normally.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Calling the real `__cxa_throw()`, forwarding the arguments. You just need to save a function pointer with the address of the real `__cxa_throw()` somewhere.

Comment: @Acorn: How do I get the address of the real `__cxa_throw`?  `&__cxa_throw` will give address of user-defined one won't it?  Actually I don't even know how your program links, why doesn't user-defined `__cxa_throw` cause link conflict with the original one?

Comment: You mean with `dlsym` or what?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos If you don't know your way around this, it will be quite hard to get a stack trace if you plan on implementing that yourself. Anyway, you can do it in several ways; the easiest being using another compilation unit where you haven't overridden it.

Comment: No, you don't need `dlsym`, just create another independent file, save the address there, and call the address in the first file.

Comment: FYI you can get a stacktrace with `boost::stacktrace::stacktrace()`

Comment: The original address can be found with `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,...)` as shown in this example https://github.com/AaronDMarasco/file-stealer/blob/master/stealer.cpp#L21

Answer (score 0):

at your throwing site you can do this:

```
try { throw 13; }
catch (...) { print_stack_trace(); rethrow;}
```

Of course, if you want this *everywhere*, then you'll need some automated editing to put it there (or a macro like this): *untested code*

```
#define THROW(x) do { \
                   try {throw(x);} \
                   catch(...) { print_stack_trace(); rethrow;} \
                 } while(false)
```

or even simpler:

```
#define THROW(x) do { \
                   print_stack_trace(); \
                   throw(x); \
                 } while(false)
```